# Repeat group header even after footer bleeds over

Tags: crystal-reports

My group header is set to repeat on each new page. My details section follows it and the group footer has a subreport. On some pages, the subreport flows onto the next page - so the group header will not display before the rest of the subreport.

How can I display the group header even after a subreport break?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use two groups and place your subreport into the group footer of the second group.

1. Create a second group (for the same field as used in group one)
2. Configure group header 1 so that it will be repeated on every page (in group assistent, i don't know the english option name)
3. use group header 1, suppress group header 2
4. put the subreport in group footer 2, suppress group header 1

If you subreport bleeds over (in group footer two) group header 1 will be repeated.

Hope this helps.